# Remove specific code from a module VBA using .DeleteLines

Tags: vba, excel

I'd like to use the `.DeleteLines`function in VBA.  As I'm not deleting all the lines in the module i need a targeted approach.  I assume there is a function like Find("FooBar").LineNumber, however I can't find it here/with google:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg264546.aspx

```
Sub Deletings()
    With Workbooks("ClassExperiment.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule
        .DeleteLines(HowDoIGetThisValue, 0)
    End With
End Sub
```

Help appreciated.

Comment: You need to get the code module and find where the line is.  Looping the lines and using instr

Comment: Are you deleting an entire procedure, or lines inside a procedure?

Comment: Why do you need to remove lines from a procedure? Surely you can use an `If` statement somewhere instead?

Comment: I'm a couple of creating buttons based on user input/data in a list, so I will need to add/remove button_Click() ... end sub from the worksheet module  if the buttons are no longer necessary.  And Comintern, an entire procedure.

Comment: @tompreston If you're totally removing a procedure, you can find the start of the procedure with ProcBodyLine (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445197(v=vs.60).aspx) and the number of lines to delete with ProcCountLines (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445200(v=vs.60).aspx)

Comment: There's a fairly comprehensive guide on looping through the lines in a code module here for anyone that ends up here in search of a similar answer http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/640258/Deconstruction-of-a-VBA-Code-Module

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you're removing the entire procedure, you can find its location with the [ProcStartLine](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445207(v=vs.60).aspx) property and the line count with [ProcCountLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa445200(v=vs.60).aspx).

```
Dim module As CodeModule
Set module = Workbooks("ClassExperiment.xlsm").VBProject.VBComponents("Module2").CodeModule

Dim start As Long
Dim lines As Long
With module
    start = .ProcStartLine("button_Click", vbext_pk_Proc)
    lines = .ProcCountLines("button_Click", vbext_pk_Proc)
    .DeleteLines start, lines
End With
```

### Warning:

This should be obvious, but I'll throw it out there anyway. ***Do not*** use this (or any other method) to alter the module that the code is running from in Debug mode. This is a good way to [break your workbook](https://stackoverflow.com/q/33698257/4088852).

Answer (score 2):

```
Sub test()

Dim vb As VBComponent
Dim i As Integer

Set vb = ThisWorkbook.VBProject.VBComponents("Module2")

For i =vb.CodeModule.CountOfLines to 1 step -1

    If InStr(1, vb.CodeModule.Lines(i, 1), "'   remove") <> 0 Then
        vb.CodeModule.DeleteLines i, 1
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

I would of also suggested using a condition statement to allow execution of the code line, rather than deleting it, when is it put back?  this could cause issues if you wish to automate that bit, as you'll need to know where it came from.

Comment: I ran it fine, but have exited the loop to be on the safe side, OP suggests it's one line to go, then no more, so wouldn't need to count on.

Comment: it might be better if you change the loop to For i = vb.CodeModule.CountOfLines To 1 step - 1 for anyone else whe might need the answer