# Trying to delete all sheets in a workbook, then add other sheets in with VBA

Tags: excel, vba, runtime-error

I keep running into errors trying to delete most sheets in a workbook, then add them back in.

I cannot delete all sheets in a workbook; at least one sheet needs to be there. Fine. So I first create a sheet called `TempSheet`.

```
targetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
'/* ...more code... */
Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Activate
Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Worksheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"
```

So now, I want to delete all of the sheets besides `TempSheet` in my workbook. So I'm trying to do this:

```
For Each ws1 In Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Worksheets
    If ws1.Name <> "TempSheet" Then
        Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Sheets(ws1.Name).Delete '/* Line X. */
    End If
Next
```

When I step through my code and get to `Line X`, I get the error `Can't enter break mode at this time`. I've tried replacing all the code on `Line X` with just `ws1.Delete`, I get the same message. I would like to at least step through the code so I can see the sheets being deleted.

The other part of my code is such that I would like to take all of the sheets from another workbook and place them in the first workbook where I deleted all of the sheets from above. My code is below:

```
Application.Workbooks("OtherWorkbook").Activate '/* Line Y. */
For Each ws2 In Application.Workbooks(sheetsWorkbook).Worksheets
    ws2.Copy After:=Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Sheets(ws1.Name)
Next
```

I put a breakpoint on `Line Y`, and after I get the `Can't enter break mode at this time` error, I hit the `Continue` button. Instead of stopping at the break point, I get the error `Run-time error '424'. Object required`, which doesn't show me which line it is referring to and doesn't let me debug (the button is grey'd out and the only button I can select is `end`).

Any suggestions on how I can achieve this?

Comment: Could you try to enclose your loop of delete with some disabling events, alerts, screenUpdating, and calculation?

Comment: What is ws1? Is it Dimed as worksheet?

Comment: Since you want to delete all worksheets why don't you start with a new workbook?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Clean up your syntax, there's no need to be redundant like for example:

```
targetWorkbook = ActiveWorkbook.Name
Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Activate
```

This is basically saying: `ActiveWorkbook.Activate`, which not only doesn't do *anything* (literally), it's also almost never necessary to rely on `Activate` or `Select` for *anything*, assuming you use appropriately scoped object variables.

```
Option Explicit
Sub foo()
Dim tempSheet as Worksheet, ws as Worksheet, wb As Workbook
Set wb = ActiveWorkbook ' Or ThisWorkbook, or Workbooks("filename.xlsx"), etc.
Set tempSheet = wb.Sheets.Add

For Each ws in wb.Worksheets
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    If ws.Name <> tempSheet.Name Then
        ws.Delete
    End If
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
Next

'Now copy the other worksheets:
Workbooks("OtherWorkbook").Worksheets.Copy After:=wb.Worksheets(1)

'Finally, remove tempsheet
tempSheet.Delete

End Sub
```

This *should* work. If you can't enter break mode, then there is something else going on with your PC.

> When I step through my code and get to Line X, I get the error Can't enter break mode at this time.

If you're stepping through the code, you're *already* in break mode, so this doesn't really make sense. See if any of these suggestions help identify the source of the error(s):

[Can't enter break mode at this time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33698257/cant-enter-break-mode-at-this-time)

> 1. From the VBE Debug menu, "Compile VBA Project", it's worth a shot.
> 2. Delete the line entirely. Run the code. Then put the line back in and try again with the breakpoint.
> 3. Add a `DoEvents` statement after the `Sheets.Add`
> 4. Use a `MsgBox` instead of a breakpoint on a `Debug.Print`. With the message box displayed, attempt to manually break using <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>fn</kbd>+<kbd>End</kbd>. (At this point, "breaking" isn't necessary but it would be interesting to see whether you can break this way)
> 5. Put a breakpoint on `Sheets.Add` instead; practically speaking, there's no reason to put the breakpoint on a `Print` statement if you can just put it on the preceding line.
> 6. Are there any Addins? If so, disable all of them and re-enable one at a time, testing to see which one may contribute to the error.

Comment: Just to come back to this. This code does not work. This code will delete all of my regular worksheets (which I found out my original code also does if I skip an iteration over sheets with buttons), but when it gets to a worksheet with buttons, then for some reason it still tells me `Can't enter break mode at this time`. I tried deleting the buttons first, but that did not work. I at least have an idea what the problem is so I'm going to play around with that for a while. Thanks for you response though.

Comment: Can you explain the rationale for deleting the sheets and copying to a new workbook? Why not just copy to a new workbook (without deleting)?

Comment: The workbook that I'm deleting from is a macro-enabled workbook that multiple people might have open at any given time. I'd like to be able to make development changes on my machine, and export all changes, including any UI changes on sheets, and then have users "reload" the workbook they are using (a button that runs a macro that deletes all sheets and copies the sheets from an xlsx) without having to close and re-open it. This is my workaround for not being able to export graphical changes on sheets.

Comment: In a perfect world, if I change some of this code to suit my app's needs and let it rip without stepping through it, then it works so I'm going to accept this as an answer and just chalk it up to something going on on my end. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You already set the `ws1` sheet object, and looping inside the workbook, you can directly delete the `ws1` object, without over complicating the syntax.

```
Dim ws1 As Worksheet

For Each ws1 In Application.Workbooks(targetWorkbook).Worksheets
    If ws1.Name <> "TempSheet" Then
        ws1.Delete
    End If
Next
```

You could just set the Workbook also like :

```
Dim wb1 As Workbook

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook ' better yet use ThisWorkbook if the workbook is the one with this code in it

For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
    If ws1.Name <> "TempSheet" Then
        ws1.Delete
    End If
Next
```

**Full code**:

```
Sub Add_DeleteWorksheets()

Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet
Dim tmpsht As Worksheet

Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook ' better yet use ThisWorkbook if the workbook is the one with this code in it
Set tmpsht = wb1.Worksheets.Add
tmpsht.Name = "TempSheet"

For Each ws1 In wb1.Worksheets
    If ws1.Name <> tmpsht.Name Then
        ws1.Delete
    End If
Next

End Sub
```

Comment: Hey. Thanks for responding. I mentioned that I already tried `ws1.Delete` and got the same error. Any other ideas on how I can implement this?

Comment: @aCarella  is `ws1` defined as `Worksheet` ?

Comment: I've implemented all of the above and still get the same error message.

Comment: @aCarella try the code under the **Full code** section

Answer (score 0):

Other that what I proposed in my comment, you can try these following two approaches

---

**Approach 1** - first insert new workbooks and then delete existing ones

this approach has the advantage you don't need any "temp" sheet, and the possible drawback of hitting memory limit in the temporary stage your active workbook has both "old" and "new" worksheets

```
Option Explicit

Sub delsheets1()
    ReDim existingSheets(1 To Worksheets.Count) As String
    Dim isht As Long

    For isht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
         existingSheets(isht) = Worksheets(isht).Name
    Next

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Workbooks("Cartel2").Worksheets.Copy After:=Worksheets(1)
    Worksheets("OtherWorkbook").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

---

**Approach 2** - first delete existing ones and then insert new workbooks

this is the same approach as yours and has the (logic only, indeed) drawback of inserting a new "temp" sheet

may be the "group" deleting technique avoids the issues you're having with your current code

```
Option Explicit

Sub delsheets2()
    ReDim existingSheets(1 To Worksheets.Count) As String
    Dim isht As Long

    For isht = 1 To Worksheets.Count
         existingSheets(isht) = Worksheets(isht).Name
    Next

    Worksheets.Add.Name = "TempSheet"

    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    Worksheets(existingSheets).Delete
    Workbooks("OtherWorkbook").Worksheets.Copy After:=Worksheets(1)
    Worksheets("TempSheet").Delete
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub
```

Comment: @aCarella, did you try one of these solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Here is yet another one. This routine deletes all sheets except one when you click on the newsheet button:

```
Public Sub Workbook_NewSheet(ByVal Sh As Object)

  Application.EnableEvents = False
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  For i = Workbooks(1).Sheets.Count - 1 To 1 Step -1
    Workbooks(1).Sheets(i).Delete
  Next
  Sheets(1).Name = "Sheet1"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True
  Application.EnableEvents = True
End Sub
```